# Back button skipping php pages

Tags: php

I have a website that consists of entirely php pages. If you do the following:

Google -> php page1 -> php page2 -> hit the browser back button and you go back to Google

I want the user to get taken back to php page1 instead of Google when they hit the back button on php page2.

I have a feeling this is to do with the automatic scripts, generated by php, that stop the browser caching pages. However, I don't want the pages to be cached as this would stop the content being updated.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Uh, this isn't going to happen unless your page1 does a redirect of some sort. Is it possible you have onclick events that are doing `window.location.replace` or something?

Comment: the history back button will bring you back to the previous cached page... if you don't cache it's not possible to go back. you'll need to overwrite the default action from the browsers back button by pointing it to the URL of page 1, but this is tricky and hard to make cross browser.

Comment: it can also be possible if your php page1 have some redirect code and on clicking that redirect code is sending it back to Google. Please see if its the case and so paste the code to identify problem in that code.

Comment: @ceejayoz there are no redirects on page1, just hyperlinks, and no onclick events either

Comment: The behaviour you describe isn't possible in that case. If you disagree, give us a link that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans thanks. I thought this might be the case. The one thing I don't understand though is if you press forward on the browser after arriving back at Google you go page2. As page2 is also not cached how can the browser remember this?

Comment: @ceejayoz Google foggywall -> go to foggywall.com -> click on one of the purple markers then hit the back button. Pls tell me if you get different behaviour or I'm missing something obvious (thanks)

Comment: Hey look, click events and location.replace calls. Exactly as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function goToTag(tagid, tagloc){
  location.replace("main.php?tagid="+tagid+"&result="+tagloc);
}
```

Switch it to `location.href="main.php?tagid="+tagid+"&result="+tagloc;` and you'll be just fine. `location.replace` does what it says on the tin - it **replaces** the current history item with the new page.